# Not able to click a value in Input drop down

Tags: selenium

I have a strange problem . I have a non select drop down with Id as below . There is a no select tag I can see in the code for this field just an input tag nor I can see the text contained in the drop down in the DOM after a select a value . **StaffSoCategory** is the text box , **SelectStaffSoCategory** is the icon for the drop down down arrow and **StaffSoCategoryValue** I believe is for the values displayed .

```
<input type="text" id="StaffSoCategory" style="width: 126px; font-weight: lighter; border: 1px solid gray; height: 25px; float: left; font-size: 12px; color: black; font-family: Arial; background-color: white;" readonly="readonly" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled">

<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>

<div id="SelectStaffSoCategory" tabindex="0" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px; border-color: gray; width: 22px; height: 29px; background-position: center; cursor: pointer; background-image: url('Images/dropdown.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; float: left; margin-left: 0px; "></div>

***<input id="StaffSoCategoryValue" type="hidden" value="">***

<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="z-index: 1; display: none; top: 584px; left: 829px; width: 148px;"></ul>
```

Once I select the first drop down value (the visible text in drop down is "Confirmed") then value comes in tag but not the visible text of the value that I see , something like below

```
<input id="StaffSoCategoryValue" type="hidden" value="BCK-Yes">
```

Is there a way to click on the first value in the drop down I tried with this value "BCK-Yes" and it said element is not visible. I tried selecting the input by Id and then trying Keys down and keys enter that also didn't work.

The code I am trying is

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;     
WebElement revenuePotential = driver.findElement(By.id("SelectStaffSoCategory")); revenuePotential.click(); 
WebElement revenuePotentialValue = driver.findElement(By.id("StaffSoCategoryValue")); 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", revenuePotentialValue);
```

Console errors I am getting are

```
StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)
(anonymous) @ StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'xx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Comment: So there has to be html to render multiple options in this drop down, and not just the input with a changing value. The input in the above example definitely seems like merely a container for the chosen value. The chosen values seem to be dynamically added to the ul tag below it. After page load, are there not li tags inside the ul tag?

If not, can you search the DOM in your developer tools for any elements on the page that contain values appearing in the drop down?

Comment: thanks @Asyranok for the comments . Yes I had checked the whole DOM tree , I can only see the ul tag and after selection in Chrome the text in the drop down is never shown while Firefox atleast shows that in value . But I cant select based on the ul tag value because the value only appears after I click on the drop down value

Comment: Asyranok - I have modified my question with the full tags

Comment: You've offered a reasonable amount of example html, so I appreciate that. But I am still having trouble visualizing everything. Is this a publically available website/page by chance? If not, do you have any javascript that you know handles events around this? If not, I will keep thinking about this and let you know if I notice something useful.

Comment: Unfortunately its not a public website code , thanks again for the help - appreciate it.

Comment: If you do not have JQuery, can you inject Jquery onto the page, and then run this:
$._data( $("#SelectStaffSoCategory")[0], "events" );

And then, whatever click-related events are bound to that, would you be so kind as to copy the javascript here. I am about 99% sure I won't figure this out without the javascript that is populating this drop down.

Comment: This is what I am getting StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)

Comment: I added jquery through the console using  --- var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);   and then ran your script and clicked on the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Well, the input is hidden, so I'm not surprised selenium tells you the element is not visible.  Methods that emulate user actions like `click()` and `sendKeys` will not be able to affect hidden elements.  However, I think the following might work:

First store that element in an object, let's say `element` and then try the following code to click on that hidden element:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();   

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

driver.get(desiredURL);

//do all the stuff you want to do before `executeScript()`

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Give that a shot?

Comment: I tried the above solution there is no exception but it didn't click on the drop down value.       WebElement revenuePotential = driver.findElement(By.id("SelectStaffSoCategory")); 
        revenuePotential.click();
        WebElement revenuePotentialValue = driver.findElement(By.id("StaffSoCategoryValue")); 
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", revenuePotentialValue);

Comment: @c-peck - have modified the question to add the full tags . Only thing changing before and after seleciton of drop down value is the hidden input fields value which becomes BCK-Yes after selcting the first value from drop down "Confirmed" . When I tried at this step JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver, the opened drop down just becomes not visible anymore and then execute script does nothing

Comment: Did you import JavascriptExecutor? Sorry just to make sure

Comment: Another stupid question: I might be missing  it but I don't think you ever said what language you are trying to use? I've just assumed Java.

Comment: Yes Java and yes I am familiar with and imported JSExecutor class.

Comment: Sorry just confirming.  Try instantiating the `JavascriptExecutor` *above* your driver actions.  Try putting it above `WebElement revenuePotential = driver.findElement(By.id("SelectStaffSoCategory"));` or just after you load your page.  Also, if you could please edit the script code you've provided in these comments into your question that would be great.  Even more code would be even better. :)

Comment: Please see my latest edit for where you should define `js`.  I think you actually have to do it before all your `driver` actions, but (obviously) after you define `driver`.

Comment: If it's still failing would you mind going to the browser's dev console and provide any console errors that might exist?

Comment: I get below exceptions --- StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25)
(anonymous) @ StaffSoJsFun.js?v=2019020100000:1
dispatch @ jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25
y.handle @ jquery-2.0.0.js?v=2019020100000:25

Comment: StaffingSOCCA.aspx?lang=English:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at ' from origin '...com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.